# How to simulate an event on a unit test with Jest, Enzyme for React-Native

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to figure out how to test an "onPress" event with Jest in a React-Native app so I can make sure the right function is called.

I went through the documentation and Google but couldn't find a solution for it in React-Native.

This is what I found that is supposed to work for React-Native with `enzyme`:

```
const mockFunc = jest.fn();
const component = mount(<MyComponent onPress={mockFunc} />);
component.simulate('press');
expect(mockFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But this doesn't work. Seems like `mount` doesn't work and I get this output:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

I tried with `shallow` instead but the `TouchableOpacity` is not getting rendered when I look at the output of the function... and you've guessed it, it doesn't work either. Not sure what to do.

Does anyone found a way to test events on React-Native?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you use enzyme, so `p.simulate('press');` should work.

Comment: enzyme `mount` doesn't seem to work with React-Native, and I don't want to use `shallow`.  `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: What type of event are you trying to test? Does it change the `state`? Or what are trying to test exactly? More details around that might help.

Comment: @JasonGaare I try to test an onPress event and see if my function gets called.

Comment: The `onPress` function is on `MyComponent` or on the `TouchableOpacity`?

Comment: The component wraps a View with a TouchableOpacity. MyComponent is basically a button wrapper, so if press it it should call onPress

Answer (score 14):

Enzyme does not support React-Native, because it's rendered differently and doesn't use the DOM. That's why you're getting the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. You can see [this issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/614) for more information. The React team is currently working to expose a `.find()` method in `react-test-renderer` to simulate actions on components. Then it should work for both React/React-native without needing a DOM environment.

There's a hack you can do (and that's what we did in our company) that is rendering a custom component that extends `TouchableOpacity` and map `onClick` to call `onPress`. Something like this:

```
const mockPressable = (name) => {
  const RealComponent = require.requireActual(name);

  class Component extends RealComponent {

    render() {
      return React.createElement(
        RealComponent.displayName || RealComponent.name,
        { ...this.props, onClick: this.props.onPress },
        this.props.children
      );
    }

  }

  return Component;
};


jest.mock('TouchableOpacity', () => mockPressable('TouchableOpacity'));
```

And in your test code, you call `component.simulate('click')`.

It's a hack and I'm not sure what are the consequences of doing this but it has worked for our use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "The React team is currently working to expose a .find() method in react-test-renderer to simulate actions on components." Any source for that?

Answer (score 11):

You should use `shallow` instead, then called `.dive()`

```
const mockFunc = jest.fn();
const component = shallow(<MyComponent onPress={mockFunc} />);    
component.dive().simulate('press');
expect(mockFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Not a solution to the general problem as you often want to use mount instead of shallow. See https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering

Answer (score 6):

I'm able to run tests like what you've described in your question in React Native. Here is my configuration:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
}

"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
  "enzyme-to-json": "^3.1.2",
  "jest": "^21.2.1",
  "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.0",
  "jest-expo": "~21.0.0",
}

"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo",
  "setupFiles": [
    "./test/jestSetup.js"
  ],
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "./node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
  ]
}
```

test/jestSetup.js

```
import { configure, shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure( { adapter: new Adapter() } )

// enzyme
global.shallow = shallow
global.render = render
global.mount = mount
```

Example component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'

const CancelButton = ( props ) =>
  <Button
    { ...props }
    onPress={ () => { props.navigation.goBack() } }
    title="Cancel"
  />

export { CancelButton }
```

Example test

```
import React from 'react'
import { CancelButton } from '../CancelButton'

test( 'onPress', () => {
  const goBackFunc = jest.fn()

  const navigation = {
    goBack: goBackFunc,
  }

  const component = shallow(
    <CancelButton
      navigation={ navigation }
    />
  )

  component.simulate( 'press' )
  expect( goBackFunc ).toHaveBeenCalled()
} )
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with shallow is a good option, works for me too. But run with shallow  means to set aside the life cycle of react native. The idea is to make it works using `mount` instead `shallow`