# How to simulate press of React Native Switch component using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a React Native component, which is basically a wrapper for [Switch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch).

It looks like this (styles and extra code removed):

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={() => this.onChange(!this.state.value)}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

This component doesn't have on `onChange` method itself, but the class it extends does. I want to make sure that when I click on this Switch, the `onChange` is called with the proper value (i.e. with either `true` or `false`).

My test looks like this (I added a mocked `onChange` method to it, to make it easier to test the action of the press):

```
  it('calls onChange with proper values when pressed', () => {
    const onChangeHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Toggle />
    );

    wrapper.instance().onChange = onChangeHandler;
    wrapper.simulate('press');


    expect(wrapper.instance().onChange).toBeCalledWith(true);
  });
```

However, this test fails, and `onChange` is not called. I'm not sure where the fault in my test is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate an event on a unit test with Jest, Enzyme for React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267903/how-to-simulate-an-event-on-a-unit-test-with-jest-enzyme-for-react-native)

Comment: This question was asked and answered almost 3 years ago. But to answer you, no, not quite. That question has no accepted answer, it doesn't mention `valueChange` and this question is specifically about the Switch component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've discovered that I don't need to simulate the press, but that I can simulate the `onValueChange` instead (i.e. the thing that is triggered when the toggle is pressed).

First I find my `Switch` component in my test, using a `testID` prop I gave it:

```
const Switch = wrapper.find('[testID="switch"]');
```

And then I use this to get around simulating a press and simulate the onChange instead:

```
Switch.simulate('valueChange');
```

This essentially has the same result as testing a press, and works for me!

Comment: This will only work for a Switch and not other components, so it's a workaround at best.

Comment: Yes, of course... the question was specifically only for a Switch component, and the answer provides a working solution and was accepted... so it's not a workaround.